# Fmod distance parameter

Tags: iphone, sdk, fmod

Is there a way to only set the distance parameter in Fmod for iPhone development? I can set 3D Max och Min Distance in Fmod Designer. I would like to only use the distance feature and not the angle feature in Fmod.

In the following code I add the position of the listener to the sound, but I want to just add the distance between the listener and the sound:

```
    listenerpos.y = (float)33.0f * DISTANCEFACTOR;
    result = system->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos, &vel, &forward, &up);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update any particular parameter for System::set3DListenerAttributes, simply pass in 0 or NULL.

```
system->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Block! Does this mean that if I want the sound to be at the distance of say 10 units I just pass in 10: system->set3DListenerAttributes(10, &listenerpos, NULL, NULL, NULL);

Comment: You could just set the Z component of the position vector to achieve   that, however if you aren't interested in doing spatialization and using directions perhaps all you need is to set the volume of a 2D sound?

Comment: I want to be able to reach the "distance" and listener angle parameters the sound designer added in this layer: http://www.sundh.com/files/fmod_setup.png Sorry for newbie question..

Comment: FMOD will calculate the distance (and angle) between the listener and the sound source depending on the position in the 3D world. You don't set the distance parameter or angle directly, it's a by-product of where you place the listener and events in the world.

Comment: With the code I still can't get it to work. I don't here any changes in the sound.. FMOD_RESULT   result     = FMOD_OK;
 FMOD_VECTOR   listenerpos;
 FMOD_VECTOR         forward         = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
 FMOD_VECTOR         up              = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
 FMOD_VECTOR         vel             = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

 listenerpos.x = 0.436432f;
 listenerpos.y = 20.0f;
 listenerpos.z = -0.432543253f;
 
 result = eventSystem->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos, &vel, &forward, &up);

    
 result = eventSystem->update();
    ERRCHECK(result);

Comment: Are the events set to 3D in FMOD Designer, if not the sound won't attenuate.